# Change the color of the dropdown text to black

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, background

I have a background in HTML that look as attached in the image. 
The CSS code is :

```
.custom-dropdown{
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin-left:190px;
-moz-appearance: none; border: 0 !important; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 14px; 
padding: 10px; width: 35%; cursor: pointer; 
background-size: 40px 37px;
display:none;
/*
color: #fff;
background: #0d98e8 url('http://www.kevinfremon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/drop-down-arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
*/
background: #e2e2e2 url('http://www.kevinfremon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/drop-down-arrow.png') no-repeat right center ;
color: #fff;

}
```

The HTML is :

```
 <select id= "dropdownlist" class="custom-dropdown">
    <option>Custom Key</option>
    <option>test</option>
    </select>
```

Now I want to make the text("Custom Key") of these dropdown list to appear inblack (without changing the background color as it goes with my template) . 
How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BCSS%5D+style+select

Answer (score 4):

Change color property in class `.custom-dropdown` from  `color:#fff` to  `color:#000`

```css
.custom-dropdown {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-left: 190px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 35%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 40px 37px;
  color: #000;

  background: #e2e2e2 url('http://www.kevinfremon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/drop-down-arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdownlist" class="custom-dropdown">
  <option>Custom Key</option>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks ,that worked :) 
Will mark it as answered 10 minutes !

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
color: black;
```

and remove this

```
color: #fff;
```